# Не закрывается выпадающее меню по клику

Tags: jquery

Написал скрипт, который открывает выпадающее меню. Скрипт умеет:

- закрывать уже открытые ранее выпадающие меню, если было открыто новое
- закрывать выпадающее меню по клику в любое место на экране

Но вот незадача. Если нажать на кнопку, которая открывает меню - меню откроется. Но если повторно нажать на эту кнопку, то меню не закрывается. Я, кажется, даже знаю, в чём проблема. Кликая на кнопку, которая открывает меню - к блоку с выпадающим меню добавляется класс active, а если нажать на эту кнопку ещё раз, то класс убирается. Но какой-то участок в коде снова добавляет этот класс. Я не могу понять, какой именно.

```
$(function() {
    var touch = $('li .menu-link.drop-down');
    var menuWrapper = $('.menu-item-list');
    var w = $(window).width();

    $(touch).on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var menu = $(this).closest('li').find('.dropdown-list');
        var isClosed = menu.is(':hidden');
        if(w > 992) { menuWrapper.find('.dropdown-list').removeClass('active') }
        else if(w < 992) { menuWrapper.find('.dropdown-list').slideUp(320) }

        if(w > 992) { menu.toggleClass('active') }
        else if(w < 992) {
            if(isClosed) { menu.slideDown(325) }
        }
    });

    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        var dropdown = $('.dropdown-list');
        if(!$('.dropdown-list').is(e.target) && $('.dropdown-list').has(e.target).length === 0 && $(touch).has(e.target).length === 0) {
            dropdown.removeClass('active');
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var menu = $('li .menu-link ~ .dropdown-list');
        if(w > 992 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Можно пример html кода, чтобы воспроизвести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в комбинации

```
menuWrapper.find('.dropdown-list').removeClass('active')
```

и

```
menu.toggleClass('active')
```

Вы сначала убираете у всех класс `active`, a потом вызываете `toggleClass`.

Добавьте `not(menu)` в

```
menuWrapper.find('.dropdown-list').not(menu).removeClass('active')
```

Comment: Супер, всё работает. Спасибо!